# Count number of alphabetic charcters in data

Tags: cobol

i have string as '   #$rahul   ' and i have to calculate number of alpha bates without using inspect verb. Also not using by ord clause for ASCII value. My instructor told me to use empty array but how it is used?? I tried but it counts for symbols also.

```
DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 WS-TABLE.
      05 WS-A OCCURS 3 TIMES INDEXED BY I.
         10 WS-B PIC A(2).
         10 WS-C OCCURS 2 TIMES INDEXED BY J.
            15 WS-D PIC X(3).

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MOVE '@#@#DEF34GHIJKL56MNOPQR' TO WS-TABLE.
   PERFORM A-PARA VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I >3 
   STOP RUN.

   A-PARA.
   PERFORM C-PARA VARYING J FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL J>2.

   C-PARA.
    if ws-table(1) equals to spaces
    continue
    else 
    add +1 to ws-count
    end-if
    DISPLAY WS-C(I,J).
```

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried, it will give us a better understanding of what you are missing out on.

Comment: i added my code but my trainer wants to use another empty array which was not understood by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from your table-definition and actual use of the table, you have basically got the idea already, except you are not sure what, specifically, to test for.

What you need to do is find the section in your COBOL documentation on *class condition* and *class tests*.

I suspect this bit of code:

```
if ws-table(1) equals to spaces
continue
else 
add +1 to ws-count
end-if
```

Has been added in haste. With your data, `ws-table(1)` will never be space, and `ws-count` is not defined.

Back to your definition. You are defining a structure with three parts (`WS-A OCCURS 3`) each of which consists of a two-byte alphabetic field followed by two three-byte alphanumeric fields. That definition is of no direct use to your task.

```
   01  the-data.
       05  FILLER OCCURS 24 TIMES
           INDEXED BY data-byte-index.
           10  the-data-byte               PIC X.
```

That will allow you to look at each byte individually. Note that you can always use good names, which will make your programs easier to understand, reduce the chance of careless errors, and make people's lives, including your own when you return to a program some time later, generally easier.

Note, you can also use reference-modification and lose out on the readability for the benefit of less typing.

*Format of your program*

Unless it is dictated to you (and although I've never seen it before in over 30 years, I have seen it a couple of time recently) there is absolutely no point in "indenting" things like the WORKKING-STORAGE section, or even paragraph/SECTION labels. They already have all the indentation they need, and further indentation adds nothing, which requiring more typing, and also causing experienced COBOL programmers to wonder why you are doing that.

Since the 1985 Standard for COBOL, the use of full-stops/periods in the PROCEDURE DIVISION is greatly relaxed. Since a full-stop/period in the wrong place can cause errors, this was a good thing. It will also be good if you take full advantage of it. Commas look far too much like full-stops/periods to be of any use in code. They never have to be there, so having them benefits nothing. Also noise-words like `THEN` can/should be avoided. Unlike commas, spacing can be a boon to the format of a program.

Here's your code above, reformatted:

```
       MOVE '@#@#DEF34GHIJKL56MNOPQR' 
                                    TO WS-TABLE
       PERFORM                      A-PARA 
         VARYING                    I 
           FROM                     1 
           BY                       1 
           UNTIL                    I > 3 
       STOP RUN
       .

   A-PARA.
       PERFORM                      C-PARA 
         VARYING                    J 
           FROM                     1 
           BY                       1 
             UNTIL                  J > 2
       .
   C-PARA.

       if ws-table ( 1 ) equal to space
           continue
       else 
           add +1                   to ws-count
       end-if 

       DISPLAY 
               WS-C ( I  J )
       .
```

Use some proper names, and it's start to look like a real program.

Note, not all people agree on how a program should be formatted. Seriously.

Comment: Yes Bill Woodger i will definitely take care of your suggestions and it really helpful to me i define ws-count but forgot to write in working storage section. Actually my trainer said that it will be solved by taking empty array but it couldn't as far as my knowledge.Again thank you so much @bill woodger.

Comment: @RahulMurade I'm not sure what they meant by "an empty array@ in this context.

Comment: Yes i also don't get what he actually wants. He just said use empty array i.e use empty table but it couldn't meet the requirement. If i got something on it or he will tell me i post it the answer.